# Active Contour Models - Lagrangian/Eulerian approches

Tags: calculus

I am reading about active contours models. It is said that this can be broadly classified as either parametric active contour models and geometric active contour models. The first one are represented explicitly as parameterized curves in a Lagragian framework, while the geometric active contours are represented implicitly as level sets of a 2-dimensional function that evolves in a Eulerian framework.

What is an Eulerian approach and an Lagragian approach?

Thanks,

Comment: Mind mentioning where (e.g. book, website) you encountered these?

Comment: The more specific you make the question the better the response you will get. Can you add more details please?

Comment: I am reading about active contours models. It is said that this can be broadly classified as either parametric active contour models and geometric active contour models. The first one are represented explicitly as parameterized curves in a Lagragian framework, while the geometric active contours are represented implicitly as level sets of a 2-dimensional function that evolves in a Eulerian framework.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to edit your question to include the information in your comment.

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close because the bot is bumping it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Eulerian vs. Lagrangian distinction in fluid mechanics:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field